# How to Expect 3 Objects with expect.objectContaining({...?

Tags: typescript, mocking, ts-jest

I am currently trying to do some test.
How can I use `toHaveBeenCalledWith` to expect 3 Object with `expect.objectContaining`?

```
it.('reports fix date', async () => {

  aService.returnValue = [{ 
     activeFrom: '2020-04-19T10:01:58.135Z'
  }];

const somethingSpy = jest.spyOn(PubSub, 'topic');

await service.report([ 
 {
  activeFrom: addDays(new Date(), 30),
 }
]},


expect(somethingSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
 expect.arrayContaining
 ([
  expect.objectContaining({ 
      activeFrom: '2020-04-19T10:01:58.135Z'
  })   
  expect.objectContaining({ 
      activeFrom: '2020-04-19T10:01:58.135Z'
  })  
  expect.objectContaining({ 
      activeFrom: '2020-04-19T10:01:58.135Z'
  }) 
 ])
);
```

Comment: What did you get? Is there any error?

Comment: I only ask whether my logick is correct or not as follows:
```
expect(somethingSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
 expect.arrayContaining
 ([
  expect.objectContaining({ 
      activeFrom: '2020-04-19T10:01:58.135Z'
  })   
  expect.objectContaining({ 
      activeFrom: '2020-04-19T10:01:58.135Z'
  })  
  expect.objectContaining({ 
      activeFrom: '2020-04-19T10:01:58.135Z'
  }) 
```